# logarithmic operation on numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a NumPy array as shown below.

```
array(['0.0189', '0.0200', '0.0212', '0.0225', '0.0239', '0.0253',
       '0.0268', '0.0284', '0.0302', '0.0320', '0.0339', '0.0360',
       '0.0381', '0.0405', '0.0429', '0.0455', '0.0482', '0.0512',
       '0.0542', '0.0575', '0.0610', '0.0647', '0.0686', '0.0728',
       '0.0772', '0.0818', '0.0868', '0.0920', '0.0976', '0.1035',
       '0.1097', '0.1164', '0.1234', '0.1309', '0.1388', '0.1472',
       '0.1560', '0.1655', '0.1755', '0.1861', '0.1973', '0.2093',
       '0.2219', '0.2353', '0.2496', '0.2647', '0.2807', '0.2976',
       '0.3156', '0.3347', '0.3549', '0.3764', '0.3991', '0.4233',
       '0.4489'], dtype=object)
```

The array name is result.I need to do logrithmic operation on this array.Below is my code.

```
20*(np.log10(float(result)/1.44))
```

When running this code, I obtained an error as shown below.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 20*(np.log10(float(result)/1.44))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

can someone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Declare your array with `dtype=np.float64`. Then `20*(np.log10(result/1.44))` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert this array to array of floats using `float`, you need to use `astype` method. Here is example use:

```py
result.astype(np.float64)
```